# Nagios / MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, nagios

Ireceived a downtime alert from Nagios that mysql was down on a host. I logged in to the host and found the following error in the mysql error.log file. What are the proper steps to troubleshoot this?

```
root@ubuntu:/var/log# tail -f mysql/error.log
101202 11:09:21 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run 
                        mysql_upgrade to create it.
101202 11:09:21  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
101202 11:09:21 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' 
                        (errno: 13)
101202 11:09:21 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: 
                        Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
101202 11:09:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
                       /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' 
                       (errno: 13)
101202 11:09:51 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run 
                        mysql_upgrade to create it.
101202 11:09:52  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
101202 11:09:52 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' 
                        (errno: 13)
101202 11:09:52 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: 
                        Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
101202 11:10:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
                       /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' 
                       (errno: 13)
101202 11:10:22 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run 
                        mysql_upgrade to create it.
101202 11:10:22  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
101202 11:10:22 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' 
                        (errno: 13)
101202 11:10:22 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: 
                        Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
```

Comment: Have you checked the file paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out why MySQL can't find its tables. Go to the MySQL data directory and look for the mysql subdirectory (corresponding to the `mysql` database which contains things like users, procs, privileges, etc.). Perhaps someone deleted the `mysql` database. Perhaps someone overwrote your my.cnf configuration file with one pointing to the wrong data directory.